# Dynamic allocation of struct

Tags: c99

I need to allocate a struct dynamically. I have a struct with this type of variables:

```c
int num;
char name[10];
float yep;
```

I need to take in input a number `i` let's assume `i=4`. So what I need to do is to take in input 4 times the `num`, the `name` and the `yep` values, and save them into an array dynamically allocated. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged c99, I thought about something added to the standard that may be interesting based on what you've asked for (edit: Variable Length Arrays -- thanks you @underscore_d). There's some bits to fill in, but this may get you started. The other approach would be to use malloc to grab the memory for the structs from the heap as opposed to the stack (using effectively alloca) as we do below. HTH:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int num;
    char name[10];
    float yep;
} mystruct;

void do_something_with_n_structs(int n) {
    mystruct structs[n];
    int idx;
    for (idx = 0; idx < n; ++idx) {
        // fill this bit in
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    printf("Enter a number: "); fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    do_something_with_n_structs(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how should i take in input the values of the struct? can you please complete the foor loop where you wrote //fill this bit in? thx

Comment: hi @wobr may you write how should i achieve the same result with an malloc? and i still do not understand how to fill the for loops (I know i can do it with gets() but it's is not safe how can I do it like with fgets()), can you help?